# when you call io:format in common_test, where does it go?

Tags: erlang

io:format calls in common_test modules don't come to the user console, although error_log messages do. I can't figure out where io:format calls DO go, either. Running ack in my repo on relevant strings turns up nothing. Does anyone know where they go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `{logdir, "logs"}.` in your spec and then the io:format goes to the log. It is done by setting the `group_leader` via `erlang:group_leader/2` to capture the IO output from your tests.

The actual output is underneath the respective test case in the log output of that test case. `logs/index.html` is your starting point to peruse.

Finally, it is somewhat loosely documented in http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/run_test_chapter.html section 6.9.

Comment: also, you can use ct:print to print stuff to the console when testing with common_test.